# How to use nano in /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, nano

I'm trying to install the most recent version of nano on my mac. I did so with homebrew, and it seems to be the first version listed in my path, i.e.

```
`which nano` -V
```

returns

```
GNU nano, version 2.4.2
...
```

and the path looks like

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

So far so good, the more recent version of `nano` is in `/usr/local/bin`.

The weird thing is that when I just run `nano -V` I get

```
GNU nano version 2.0.6 (compiled 16:25:25, Sep  9 2014)
...
```

Any idea as to why the version pointed to by `which` wouldn't be the same as the one pointed to by my terminal?

Comment: Obligatory learn `vim` | `emacs` comment.

Comment: I guess I'm glad someone is watching out for me, but I already use `emacs` for 95% of my coding. Sometimes I just want something a bit ... lighter

Comment: Then I would say go with vim over nano, for a light editor, it is still pretty powerful. :D

Comment: I could do that, but then I'd have to learn `vim`, which confuses the hell out of me. (Before this degrades into [something utterly worthless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war), I should say that this is in no way a claim that text editor X is somehow better than text editor Y. Emacs confused the hell out of me for about a year too. Now that I have a text editor that does what I want, I'd rather be confused by the actual code I'm writing, or… I don't know, doing my actual job.)

Comment: Hey man, I never bashed the use of emacs, I bashed the use of nano ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just installed the new version of `nano`, and you're using `bash` as your shell, you may need to get `bash` to forget the path it cached for `nano` by running the `hash -r` shell built-in command.

Other shells may have similar path caches with other ways to flush them.

Comment: Awesome, that had me so confused.